# Creating an universal comparator to sort a tree map problem

Tags: java, comparator, treemap

This is where I'm at:

```
public final Comparator<Object> ID_IGN_CASE_COMP = new Comparator<Object>() {

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        String s1 = null;
        String s2 = null;
        try {
            Class c = o1.getClass();
            IO.println(c.getName()); //java.lang.string instead of Animal
            Method method = c.getMethod("getId");
            s1 = (String)method.invoke(o1);
            s2 = (String)method.invoke(o2);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {}
        return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
    }
};

private Map< String, Animal> _animals = new TreeMap< String, Animal>(ID_IGN_CASE_COMP);
```

I'm getting `java.lang.string` instead of `Animal` class. Any idea on how can I solve this issue?

Comment: You mean the issue being that you don't understand what a TreeMap is for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TreeMap is ordered in terms of its keys. The keys of your map are Strings. What problem are you actually solving?

Answer (score 0):

The Map is based on the ordering of the keys (not values), so that explains why you've got a String instead of an Animal.

Answer (score 0):

You are *almost* there, If you use a **TreeSet** instead of a TreeMap, you can use your comparator on one of the fields of the Animal class.

Btw, you are using reflection to get to the Id field, if the `Animal` baseclass contains the `.getId()` method, you can cast and call the method without reflection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort a `Map` by value, and the current `String` key is actually a property of `Animal`, then best way is probably to create a `LinkedHashMap` based on a `SortedSet<Animal>` or maybe a `List<Animal>` which is sorted using `Collections#sort()`.

```
Set<Animal> animalSet = createAndSortItSomehow();
Map<String, Animal> animalMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Animal>();
for (Animal animal : animalSet) {
    animalMap.put(animal.getSomeStringYouWantAsKey(), animal);
}
```

Only pitfall is that you have to re-sort if whenever you want to add a new `Animal` to the map.